# Strategy for defence in street fight for good kicker who throw punches in short distance

Tags: tae-kwon-do, boxing, kicking, krav-maga, streetfight

What is the best strategy for street fight when your rival is expert in kicks (Taekwondo black belt) and when you close distance he throws punches in very aggressive way and then reopens distance for kicks. His kicks are fast, accurate and very strong in a way you can hardly see them until they hit you. If you have a good knowledge in Krav Maga for instance, is there a way to win such a rival?

Comment: If you are in a street fight and your opponent backs up for distance, is there a reason you can't run away?  If it's not a competition or sport, why would you hang around to keep fighting this person?

Comment: Thanks, in street fight there are situations you can't run away and must fight. In sports, if someone from Taekwondo joins group of other styles.

Comment: In street fights, there's usually not a lot of backing up, jabbing/long kicks, and keeping distance, at least if it's an assault.  What you are describing is inconsistent with a street attack and more in line with two people choosing to fight in the street... usually over ego.

Comment: Thanks. The most important issue here is how to win such a fight/ situation. What is the best strategy? Is there a way to win him when he throw punches (He is not a good boxer)?

Comment: Although I agree heavily with Bankuei that running away seems like the only winning move; If you have no other options I would advise using a leg-catch take down and moving to the ground where TKD is weaker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a street assault, the normal action is that an opponent will be attacking you by surprise, possibly from behind, or where you are unable to fully maneuver.  However, the situation you describe the attacker is constantly preferring to take distance and do probing attacks rather than focus on getting you on the ground/against a wall.

The reason you don't see this in assaults is that it gives the victim time and distance to respond.

Since your attacker is being kind to you, take advantage of it.

If they slide back for distance, then use that opportunity to run.

If that's not enough, circle yourself around terrain - light poles, trees, parked cars, fire hydrants, etc. to remove your opponent's ability to dance in and out.  This allows you to buy additional time - to run.

If you're still unable to get distance, consider if you have any self defense tools or weapons available, or can makeshift a weapon.  Since you're asking a very specific question head of time and not as a past example, I can only assume you're EXPECTED a PARTICULAR individual to attack you.  There's no reason to not a) avoid the areas they're in, and b) arm yourself accordingly.  Pepperspray, well trained, will help a lot.  Striking devices would also be useful, particularly to punish striking limbs.

If you are boxed in (which is rare for range fighters to do, since the conditions that box you in usually prevent them from circling which is what they're most comfortable with) you can even grab ANYTHING on them and slam it into one of the walls.  You'll probably take a couple of hits along the way, but break a hand or twist an ankle on them and your odds of getting away increase drastically.